# Bootstrap Button wrong font after adding link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Datensätze
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success pull-right" id="command-add" data-row-id="1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> bla</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right" id="command-import" data-row-id="1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#importFrm').slideToggle();" </span> blu</button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="importFrm">
                <input type="file" name="file" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="importSubmit" value="go!">
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ddt3skr6/

As you can see, I want to show the import option only after clicking the import button. I set the link, but now the font of this button is very ugly...

Maybe someone could help me finding a solution for the correct function and font of this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close your `<span>` tag after the button that has `id="command-import".`

Also in your case you only need to slide it down, so firstly it has to be slide up then, on click you can slide it down.

You can check this  [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmwZad) you will have to click the HDD icon "Datensätze importieren" for toggle.

Comment: Isn't it after "slideToggle();" </span>?

Comment: Yes, you have to add a `>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it right: <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success pull-right" id="command-add" data-row-id="1">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> bla</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right" id="command-import" data-row-id="1">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"  <href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#importFrm').slideToggle();"> </span> blu</button>

Comment: Check the demo, maybe it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This tag `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hdd"  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#importFrm').slideToggle();"` There was no end character `>`

And Last ‍‍`div` in last line is useless.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w7d4bskg/1/)